# Date Difference in 2 dates from separate data sources in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am calculating difference in 2 dates in tableau which comes from 2 excel files. For this i have already blended the data however after researching and trying i cant figure out a correct calculation

```
`DATEDIFF('day',MAX([Forecast Date1]),(ATTR([Drawdown].[Actual Drawdown Date])))`
```

tried this calculation but it results in blank

The expected outcome should give a difference in number of days between these 2 days

Comment: can you share excel files with sample data?

Comment: If their is any error in the formula we can help if output is problem then if you can share the files then we can give the correct output